# How to enable open XML Package Editor power tool for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, excel

I want to create customized ribbon on my excel sheet. I saw some of the tutorial (e.g, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hn3Qkp4Jw34) where they used **Open XML package editor power tool for visual studio 2010** and worked on some xml configuration file to add ribbon. Hence I downloaded the tool and installed it. But when I drag and drop the excel file to the VS-2010, the file instead of opening in the VS editor it is opening in its new excel window. I tried to do same thing for a word file but still it is opening in new word window instead of opening in VS editor. Anybody could you please help me regarding this. I was using Visual Studio 2012 but then I came to know that Open XML package editor power tool for visual studio 2010 won't work for VS-2012 hence Installed VS-2010 but still getting same problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Anup, Have you tried going to File->Open from Visual Studio?

If that opens it from an Office client application as well, then the Visual Studio Package Editor is not the default option for opening documents of that file extension.

If the document is a part of a solution (you can just create a new blank solution and add it in) you can right click on the file from Solution Explorer and choose "Open With", from there you can choose to open that file as a "Package File", and you can also select this as the default way to "open" files of that extension in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Microsoft and have just updated this plugin to work with VS2012 and 2013. Drag and drop should work in all the VS versions (I just tested it) but perhaps it's worth trying downloading the [updated extension from the Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b) and seeing if it works for you in the newer VS version.